# multi dimensional mysql select?

Tags: mysql, join, multidimensional-array

```
table: car_profile
carid, carname, caryear, cartype

table: user_profile
userid, username, useremail

table: user_car
id, carid, userid, status
FC: carid, userid
```

One `carid` can have multiple `userid` in table `user_car` (One car can be used by multiple persons)

Given a `carid`, I want to select `caryear`, `cartype`, `[userid, username, useremail]`. The one inside the bracket should be an array in itself, as multiple `userid` is possible. I am not sure if this is posisble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT can return a single value, a row of values, or a table of rows. There is no higher dimensional option. Below, the multiple `userid`, `username`, `useremail` will show up on separate rows.

```
SELECT cp.caryear, cp.cartype, up.userid, up.username, up.useremail
FROM car_profile as cp
LEFT JOIN user_car as uc
ON uc.carid = cp.carid 
LEFT JOIN user_profile as up
ON uc.userid = up.userid
WHERE cp.carid = carid
ORDER BY cp.caryear, cp.cartype
```

Comment: If you add an `ORDER BY cp.caryear, cp.cartype` then all results corresponding to one car year and car type will appear after each other, and the program that makes the query can use that to build an array.

Comment: Thank you. I did the same, and then rearranged them into associative array in backend. I will put this as accepted answer.